# Pass data from profile screen to custom navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I am displaying profile pic and username in my app drawer. But drawer updating when I restart the app again. I am new to react native so I don't know how to refresh my drawer after changing profile pic in my profile screen. I searched about it and found it can be done by redux, but I am not getting any proper code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try by saving the userData in the Redux and get the userData from the redux in the Drawer Component so whenever data changes it will be reflected the Component where it is being used.

check out the official docs for redux.

**https://react-redux.js.org**